# Use =MAX on external workbook using certain variables

Tags: excel, hyperlink, macros, max, vba

I'm a total noob when it comes to code, so apologies for what you're about to see.

I have a workbook with a list of orders from suppliers, along with their value. I'm trying to create a macro that does the following, but I'm running into a brick wall.

[image]

I want the macro to check cell B of the active row, then access they hyperlinked workbook and output the =MAX value in cell D of the active row.

```
Sub Find_PO_Total()

Range("Supplier" & ActiveCell.Row).Select

If Range("Supplier" & ActiveCell.Row) = "Supplier1, Supplier2" Then
Range("Value" & ActiveCell.Row).Max ("_hyperlink_here_!G1:G709")

ElseIf Range("Supplier" & ActiveCell.Row) = "Supplier3" Then
    Range("Value" & ActiveCell.Row).Max ("_hyperlink_here_!H1:H709")

ElseIf Range("Supplier" & ActiveCell.Row) = "Supplier4, Supplier5" Then
    Range("Value" & ActiveCell.Row).Max ("_hyperlink_here_!I1:I709")

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i have made the required changes to your code

```
Sub Find_PO_Total()

If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "Supplier1" Or Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "Supplier2" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = "=MAX(_hyperlink_here_!G1:G709)"

ElseIf Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "Supplier3" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = "=MAX(_hyperlink_here_!H1:H709)"

ElseIf Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "Supplier4" Or Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = "Supplier5" Then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = "=MAX(_hyperlink_here_!I1:I709)"
End If

End Sub
```